# How to set QRCode version in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, swift4, qr-code

Using the Core Graphic library I'm able to generate almost any types of . QR-Code, however, I have no control over the version being used by Swift.

According to http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html there are several versions, which are

current code:

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
filter?.setValue(vcard, forKey: "inputMessage")
filter?.setValue("M", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

if let output = filter?.outputImage {
  let scaleX = qrCode.frame.size.width / output.extent.size.width
  let scaleY = qrCode.frame.size.height / output.extent.size.height
  let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY)
  let scaledOutput = output.transformed(by: transform)
  self.qrCode.image = UIImage(ciImage: scaledOutput)
}
```

does not let me control the version of the qr-code being used. It only makes sure that the resulting image is not blurred and this is it.

Is there a way, as for the correction level, to pass qr-code version to the Core Image lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator).

> Generates an output image representing the input data according to the ISO/IEC 18004:2006 standard.

Which I believe is version 2. Version 3 is the ISO/IEC 18004:2015 standard. There is no way to change the QR version according to the docs.

Comment: ok. so, is there a pod that would offer a better control on this?

Comment: By the way, I think that you are confuing the version with the ISO ref. The version defines the size of the image and number of pixels in the inage (see the link I mentioned in my original question) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code

Comment: Yeah maybe you are right, but the documentation literally does not mention the version, so you cannot control it using the built in QR reader. The docs only refer to that ISO ref, which I wasn't sure whether it also referred to the version. It does track 'editions'